# How to simplify this in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to transform an object into a particular array.

Here is my example object :

```
const object = {
  details: 'Here are some details',
  info: 'Here is a bit of info',
  more: 'Wanna see more?',
  random: 'Title 4',
  random2: 'Title 5',
  ...
 }
```

I want the following output :

```
[
  {
    "tabLabel": "Some details", // details 
    "tabContent": "Here are some details"
  },
  {
    "tabLabel": "Explanations", // info
    "tabContent": "Here is a bit of info"
  },
  {
    "tabLabel": "Continue your journey", // more
    "tabContent": "Wanna see more?"
  }
]
```

The solution I went with :

```
const newObj = Object.entries(object).map(([key, val]) => {
  if (key === 'details') {
    dataArray.push({ tabLabel: "Some details", tabContent: val });
  }

  if (key === 'info') {
    dataArray.push({ tabLabel: 'Explanations', tabContent: val });
  }

  if (key === 'more') {
    dataArray.push({ tabLabel: 'Continue your journey', tabContent: val });
  }
});
```

How I can do this more elegantly ?

Comment: What's `dataArray` in your solution? Where are you putting the overall result, `newObj` or `dataArray`? Also, regardless of that, your solution does not produce the output you've said you want. Nowhere are you handling converting `details` to `Some details`.

Comment: Hint: `const v = { details: 'Some details', ... }; d.push({ tabLabel: v[key], ...})`

Comment: This depends... "details", "info" and "more" -- are those keys _special_? Will they be hardcoded and not expected to change, or should they be easily configurable? Do you need localization?

Comment: in a map you need to return a value if not do a forEach.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder indeed ! I edited the answer, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Vilx- Yes, those are supposed to be hardcoded. I've found the answer from Del to be best in my use case. Actually no need to iterate.

Comment: @RebootGG - Very good! That would have been my answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
const newObj = [ // In fact is an Array
  {
    "tabLabel": "Some details",
    "tabContent": object.details
  },
  {
    "tabLabel": "Explanations", // info
    "tabContent": object.info
  },
  {
    "tabLabel": "Continue your journey", // more
    "tabContent": object.more
  }
]
```

As you need the map to concrete keys, there is no need to iterate, so I think is cleared in this way.

Comment: You are right, I need to hardcode the "tabLabel" values so it is actually the simplest and natural solution in my opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
const object = {
  details: 'Here are some details',
  info: 'Here is a bit of info',
  more: 'Wanna see more?'
}
const signification = {
  details: "Some details",
  info: "Explanations",
  more: "Continue your journey"  
}
const array = Object.entries(object).map (x => {
    return {
    tabLabel: x[1],
    tabContent: signification[x[0]]
  }
})
console.log(array)
```

The result is conform :

```
[{
  tabContent: "Some details",
  tabLabel: "Here are some details"
}, {
  tabContent: "Explanations",
  tabLabel: "Here is a bit of info"
}, {
  tabContent: "Continue your journey",
  tabLabel: "Wanna see more?"
}]
```

You only need to implement `signification` and he need to have the same length as `object`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Map on JavaScript and make the code much clearer.

```
const object = {
    details: 'Here are some details',
    info: 'Here is a bit of info',
    more: 'Wanna see more?',
    random: 'Title 4',
    random2: 'Title 5',
};

const label = new Map()
    .set('details', "Some details")
    .set('info', "Explanations")
    //so on
;

const array = Object.entries(object).map(([key, val]) => {
    return {
        tabLabel: label.get(key),
        tabContent: val
    };
})
console.log(array)
```

Comment: I went with Del's approach, but this way of doing it is definitely interesting. Thanks for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

```js
const obj = 
      { details : 'Here are some details'
      , info    : 'Here is a bit of info'
      , more    : 'Wanna see more?'
      } 

const Labels = 
    { details : 'Some details'
    , info    : 'Explanations'
    , more    : 'Continue your journey'
    }
 
const newObj = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v],i) =>({ tabLabel:Labels[k], tabContent:v} ))

console.log( newObj )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It indeed works as intended, thank you for taking the time, went with Del's solution but I will integrate yours in I want to separate the labels, which would be cleaner